# Can MDM on an iPhone restrict custom keyboard usage?

Tags: mobile, ios, iphone, keyloggers

I have an iPhone that runs 13.3.1 (latest at this time). It's a corporate phone and has an MDM profile installed. I've been using the phone for almost 2 years now with a custom keyboard (Google Keyboard). However, after recently traveling to the States, I noticed that my phone is forcing me to use the default Apple keyboard every time I try to type something. It's been happening since 3 weeks now and this change was not caused by a system upgrade, I remember not changing/installing anything around the time when this started. It's almost like my iPhone woke up one day and did not want me to use another keyboard, even after I had been using one for years now (jealous much?).
The MDM profile installed doesn't mention having control over keyboard. The moment I start typing, I get force switched to the Apple keyboard (without suggestions). And while I can switch to the Apple keyboard with suggestions, I can't use my other keyboard even though it's set as default.

This behavior began very randomly and at this point I wonder if it's just paranoia or legit. I work in this field and so it probably isn't irrational paranoia but I'm just looking for a logical answer. Does anyone know what this is about or has experienced similar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! iOS MDM can limit custom keyboard for *managed corporate apps*.

> **Custom Keyboard extensions** provide keyboards beyond the ones already
>   built into iOS. Managed Open In can prevent unauthorized keyboards from
>   appearing in your corporate apps.
>
> see page 7 of https://www.apple.com/business/docs/resources/Managing_Devices_and_Corporate_Data_on_iOS.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but if an organization adds a rule to an existing MDM profile, can it be implemented on devices without notice?

Comment: The organization can do anything it wants, anytime it wants, without any notice at all. That's what "Corporate Managed" means.